# How to use (named) slots on hybrid VueJS app

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to create a hybrid webapp (Laravel + VueJs) where I am using Laravel for the backend (routing, etc.) and use dynamic VueJS components for them.

I want to use **(named) slots** to pass in content from my blade templates into the VueJs components.

When I load the page, I briefly see my content in the slot but then, just a couple of milliseconds latter, it gets blanked out.

Here is the code I have

**main.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import App from './components/App';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    render: h => h(App),
});
```

**Main blade file**

```html
<div id="app">
  This is content
</div>
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
    <slot></slot>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'App',
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

What am i Missing here?
Its like it immediately overrides the slot content (blanks it out)

PS: I am using VueJs 2.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to pass the slot value when you create the component with the `render` property. The template syntax might be easier to use in your use case instead.

Remove the `render` property from your **Vue** object and register your app component with something like

```
Vue.component('app', require('./components/App.vue').default);
```

Then your blade template can contain the following:

```html
<div id="app">
  <app>This is content</app>
</div>
```

The reason you’re seeing the content and then it disappears is that your html content gets rendered and then replaced by your Vue template that has an empty slot. You can test this by adding some more content to your Vue template and see if it gets rendered. If it does then it means the slot value isn’t passed through correctly.

Comment: This works perfectly. I was trying to avoid having the `<app></app>` element. But apparently that cant be done...Now ill need to test if i can easily use component in components :-) Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the initial content when rendering the app:

```js
render(h) {
   return h(App, null, [this.$el.innerHTML])
}
```

See `h` (createElement) description here:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#createElement-Arguments

But that just put the content in your App component, I think it won't be reactive anyway. Probably try to check the X-template feautres to achive blade and vue mixing:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#X-Templates